# Generic type as parameter for result

Tags: java, generics, gson

I want to create a generic method to return deserialized data. The idea is to pass through parameter a `Type.class` and when it deserialize using `Gson`, it returns a collection or a single object from `Type`.

For example:

```
public class Client {
    String id;
    String name;

    /* getters and setters */
}

public class Account {
    String number;
    String bank;

   /* getters and setters */
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Client> clients = Utils.getList(Client.class, "");
       Account account = Utils.getSingle(Account.class, "number = '23145'");
    }
}

public class Utils {

    public static Class<? extends Collection> getList(Class<?> type, String query) {
        //select and stuff, works fine and returns a Map<String, Object> called map, for example

         Gson gson = new Gson();
         JsonElement element = gson.fromJsonTree(map);

         //Here's the problem. How to return a collection of type or a single type?
         return gson.fromJson(element, type);
    }

    public static Class<?> getSingle(Class<?> type, String query) {
        //select and stuff, works fine and returns a Map<String, Object> called map, for example

         Gson gson = new Gson();
         JsonElement element = gson.fromJsonTree(map);

         //Here's the problem. How to return a collection of type or a single type?
         return gson.fromJson(element, type);
    } 
}
```

How can I return a single object from `Type` or a list of it?

Comment: And... what's the question?

Comment: A hint: When asking for help, make it easy for people to understand what you are asking. Burying the question in code comments does not make it easy.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need change method signature to generic type:

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> type, String query)
```

and

```
public static <T> T getSingle(Class<T> type, String query)
```

`getSingle` method should start working, but for method `getList` you need to change implementation:

1. create `Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();`
2. `return gson.fromJson(element, listType);`

you can find more information about `com.google.gson.Gson` from [javaDoc](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Shouldn't I set `new TypeToken<List<type>` somehow?